# How can I calculate the time complexity of this code?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm going through HackerRank problems and I have this question:

> Given a list of minerals embedded in each of John's rocks, display the
>   number of types of gemstones he has in his collection. For example,
>   the array of mineral composition strings is ['abc', 'abc', 'bc]. The
>   minerals b and c appear in each composite, so there are 2 gemstones.

I have a solution, but I would like to ask about the time complexity:

```
def gemstones(arr):
    counter = 0
    char_set = set(''.join(arr))
    for ch in char_set:
        if all(ch in word for word in arr):
            counter+=1
    return counter
```

Am I right in thinking that the time complexity is O(n+m) where n is the number of elements in char_set and m is number of elements in arr?

Answer (score 0):

The correct complexity is O(N):

```
def gemstones(arr) :
    return len(set(arr))
```

This will return the correct number of gemstones, ignoring the duplicates.

You don't have to count the minerals for that.

---

Below there's a link to the HR problem, for that problem the solution is:

```
def gemstones(arr):
    x = set(arr[0])
    for a in arr :
        x.intersection_update(set(a))
    return len(x)
```

Comment: The wording of the problem is confusing, but I don't think that gives you the right answer, IIUC it's the number of minerals that appear in every rock, so for `['abc', 'zbc', 'bc']` the answer would be 2, not 3

Comment: @SpoonMeiser `['abc', 'zbc', 'bc']` are all different, so we have 3 gems

Comment: this is my point, I think you've interpretted the question wrong - only `b` and `c` appear in each of those, so the answer is 2

Comment: @SpoonMeiser then for `['a', 'b', 'c']` we have an answer 0 (zero)?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser why he keeps those worthless stones then? =)

Comment: @SpoonMeiser and how about the collection `['a']` -- how many gems are there?

Comment: This looks like the problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/gem-stones/problem

Comment: I think your updated answer has different complexity though

Comment: @SpoonMeiser why is that? the number of the minerals is 28 (`a-z`), so it's a constant. the number of stones gets us O(N) -- `N` is the number of stones, yeah =)